# How to make list comprehension faster?

Tags: python

How can I make my code faster? The code performs poorly for large input

Input: texts (list of lists)

```
texts = [['HAMLET', 'HAMLET', 'THE', 'THE', 'THE']]
```

Output: replace all strings in texts that appear less than 3 with R

```
modified_texts = ['R', 'R' ,'THE', 'THE', 'THE']
```

This is what I have so far:

```
flat_texts = [item for sublist in texts for item in sublist]
modified_texts = []
for x in set(flat_texts):
 if flat_texts.count(x) < 3:
   while x in flat_texts:
     modified_texts = [item.replace(x,"R") for item in flat_texts]
return modified_texts
```

Comment: I'd start from converting `flex_texts` to a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). It's highly likely that `flat_texts.count(x)` makes it slow.

Comment: Please provide a [MRE]. The dangling `return` shows the code is incomplete and the `while x in flat_texts:` would create an infinite loop. This code would not be slow, it would never finish at all.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `collections.Counter`, and `... if ... else ...` clause:

```py
from collections import Counter

texts = [['HAMLET', 'HAMLET', 'THE', 'THE', 'THE']]
texts_flat = [x for sublist in texts for x in sublist]

counter = Counter(texts_flat)
output = [x if counter[x] >= 3 else 'R' for x in texts_flat]
print(output) # ['R', 'R', 'THE', 'THE', 'THE']
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `itertools.chain` to flatten the list and `collections.Counter` to count the occurrences. Then a list comprehension to change the elements:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(texts))
texts2 = [['R' if c[e]<3 else e for e in l]
          for l in texts]
```

Output: `[['R', 'R', 'THE', 'THE', 'THE']]`

##### flat output variant

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(texts))
texts2 = ['R' if c[e]<3 else e for l in texts
          for e in l]
```

Output: `['R', 'R', 'THE', 'THE', 'THE']`

Comment: I tested this with %%timeit and it was fast. using itertools improved the speed by 1 us